# Errors using a customised beamer theme: ua-beamer

Tags: beamer, installing

Might I ask any help in using a customised beamer theme?
The theme seems to be called ua-beamer.

The GitHub repository can be found here:
https://github.com/nschloe/ua-beamer.

The GitHub project can directly be downloaded as a ZIP-folder here: https://github.com/nschloe/ua-beamer/archive/master.zip.

I cannot create a working pdf-document at the moment. There is some explanation in the installation.tex file (located in the doc sub-folder), but even this document I cannot compile to pdf. The whole project seems coded pretty neat, but the explanation is hard to understand for me, perhaps since I don't have a lot of experience using customised beamer-packages.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you give us a very basic example on how you include the theme in your document. Right now, i don't know if you installed the files not to the right place, or calling it wrong or maybe the TeX system is corrupted. So, code ready for us to test would be great.

Comment: Hi there. I am not even using any code right now. Ofcourse I have the basic knowledge to make a beamer document using the standard tex-lay-out, but I have absolutely no clue on how to make a beamer document using the above-specified lay-out (ua-beamer): I have not written any specific code yet, since I wouldn't know how to incorporate the new lay-out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the files and move them to the folders they belong to. Usually, package writers prepare the needed directory structure, but in this case, unfortunatelu not.

If you just want to use the theme, copy the package files found in the `theme` folder to your working directory. This is the shortcut for now, but if you want to use the theme over and over again, do the solid approach.

You can read more about the TeX Directory Structure in `texdoc tds`. I don't want to call every single file and its destination here and now, as it takes aabout three minutes to figure this out.

Typesetting the documentation might be a good idea, but one should mention that the use of XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is required.

Once the files are where they can be found by tex, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{UniversiteitAntwerpen}
\author{Vincent}
\title{the beamertheme of the University of Antwerp looks nice}
\subtitle{really nice}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: vincentUabeamer]

Comment: oThanks for the clear comment, however - even when my new beamer-document (let's call it beamer.tex, which consists only of the 8 lines of code given by @Johannes) is positioned inside the **theme sub-folder** of the lay-out-folder (I would guess LaTeX would be able to find the lay-out-files then), I still get an error when executing your code, namely:

`No file beamer.nav.  
.\beamer.tex:6: Missing $ inserted.  
<inserted text>  $`.

I will now try to look into online explanatory files about TeX Directory Structure. Thanks for the advise and thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: That are two ifferent things, the first quite usual for a first run. The second should not happen. Can you please show the log-file of my code example, copied to the question above?

Comment: Sure, with pleasure. I uploaded the log-file here (since I don't know how of any option to post a long file on stackexchange): http://we.tl/v8NO5Ihdii.

Comment: Give your main another name. Additionally, the theme includes image files that are not found by LaTeX. Place them in your working folder as well.

Comment: Great! Putting the images inside the working folder directly solved the issue! Problem solved, many thanks.